# Can't add JsonArrayRequest to singleton queue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I have been following a course on Android Development and making a trivia app that uses a json. I have to use a singleton to get the data from the web. 
So here is a file QuestionBank.java, which will get the data from web and put it into a logd (for now just to test). Then, once it is working, I'll have to code it to put the data in a Question object:

```
package com.example.triviaapp.data;

import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.triviaapp.controller.AppController;
import com.example.triviaapp.models.Question;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class QuestionBank {
        ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json";
    public List<Question> getQuestions(){
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                (JSONArray) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
        return null;
    }

}
```

In the line AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest); I am getting this error:

> getInstance(Context) in AppController cannot be applied to ().

I think I may need to provide something inside these brackets....However, the person in the video uses exactly thos code and does not face any problem.

To clarify, AppController is the Singleton file and this QuestionBank.java is a normal java class which does not implement or extend anything.

Edit: here's the AppController class:

```
package com.example.triviaapp.controller;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController {
    private static AppController instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private static Context ctx;

    private AppController(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AppController(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
       return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

Comment: update your question with the AppControlle class also

Comment: @AgentP Please see edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the context in your get instance, ie instead of:

```
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
```

you need

```
AppController.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
```

You can achieve that replacing:

```
public List<Question> getQuestions(){
```

with

```
public List<Question> getQuestions(Context context){
```

the context can be your activity. So in your activity, you can call:

```
getQuestions(this)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was stuck for days.